# Is there a way to capture the changes to a textarea?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is what I am working with right now

```
$("#text").on("input", function(event){

    console.log("The changes are:" + SomeDataThatIDontKnowHowToAccess);

});
```

I realize that this could potentially break for the backspace/pasting over text/insert/delete. I don't really know how this could be handled, maybe have delete/insert/override events... I'd rather not roll my own solution.

**An Example**

The user pastes `something` in a blank textarea

`{eventType:'insert', value:'something'}`

shows up in the console

Comment: Changes as the user makes edits, or when they are done and leave the textarea?

Comment: @j08691 as the user makes edits.

Comment: You could try capturing all keypresses and display changes on x intervals.

Comment: I do not follow the question. Do you want to know the text before and the text after changes have been completed? I think that you need to post an example.

Comment: @jholloman but then you wouldn't get the values of the copy pastes.

Comment: @johnthexiii right, so your best bet may be to store the old, and compare it to the new onchange.

Comment: Storing the new and old value really is the absolute best way to write this code.  You can use the mentioned library to build the change events that you want.  The man reason I recommend storing both the new and old instead of just the changes is because -- if there is a bug in your code and you realize that you didn't capture the changes properly, the only way you can fix that is by building the change list with updated code.  A wise man once gave computer programmers this advice: "Never throw away data.  You may need it sometime."

Answer (score 1):

Write the old value to some place you can persist on focus. Then you can use your own logic in the `change` event to find the differences between old and new values

```
$('#text').on('focus', function () {
    //THIS LINE IS INCORRECT [what was wrong with my fiddle]... assignment is parameter *doh*
    //$(this).data('oldValue') = $(this).val();
    //THIS IS THE CORRECT LINE
    $(this).data('oldValue', $(this).val());
}).on('change', function() {
    alert('Old Value: ' + $(this).data('oldValue') + '\nNew Value: ' + $(this).val());
});
```

Fiddle for ya: http://jsfiddle.net/BLSully/jqbAr/1/ [*fixed*]

Comment: I think your fiddle is broken I consistently get `undefined` for old value.

Comment: @johnthexiii: so it is. Fixed. Sorry about that

Answer (score 1):

Two things you have to do here. First, you have to cache the last value. This way,when the new value comes in, you have what to compare it with.

Second, you need to take a look (and download) a [string diff function made available by John Resig](http://ejohn.org/projects/javascript-diff-algorithm/). You'd get the output of the diff into a div's html. The result looks awesome.

Then, your solution would look like this:

```
$("#text").data('lastvalue', $("#text").val());
$("#text").on("input", function(event){
    var diff = diffString($("#text").data('lastvalue'), $("#text").val()); 
    $('#changesdiv').html("The changes are:" + diff);
    $("#text").data('lastvalue', $("#text").val());
});​
```

**Update**

I fixed a few errors on script and got a jsfiddle running at http://jsfiddle.net/m3KAa/6/

IMHO, this `diffString` function is really awesome.

Comment: @BLSully It's a really good function. Take a look at the assembled jsfiddle and see how nicely the result gets displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

// This event can be used when the textarea loses focus

```
$("#text").on("change", function(event){

    console.log("The changes are:" + $(this).val() );

});
```

// This event can be used user starts typing and key is presed

```
 $("#text").on("keyup", function(event){

        console.log("The changes are:" + $(this).val() );

    });
```

//

```
$("#text").on("input",   // Here input is not a event you are supposed to used
```

// Try using change event instead..

Comment: These are not the changes, this is the new value

Answer (score 0):

if you need get current value you need to use keyup event

```
$("#text").on("keyup ", function(event){
    console.log("The changes are:" + $(this).val() );
});
```